# Q>How to fix "DML currently not allowed" when accessing visualforce page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, force.com, dml

I edited my class and saved it successfully but when I accessed my page which uses the class, I get an error of

**DML currently not allowed** 
An unexpected error has occurred. Your development organization has been notified.

here is my controller

```
public class DefinitionController {

    public DefinitionController() {
        this.DefTable();
    }

    public void DefTable() {
        listplatforms = [select Name, Status__c from Platform__c];

        for (Platform__c idlistplatforms : [select Id from Platform__c]) {
            List<Def__c> existplatforms = [select Platform__c from Def__c where Platform__c = :idlistplatforms.Id];

            if (existplatforms.size() > 0) {
                idlistplatforms.Status__c = 'Set';
                //update idlistplatforms;
                System.debug('Found' + idlistplatforms);
            } else {
                idlistplatforms.Status__c = 'Not Set';
                //update idlistplatforms;
                System.debug('Not Found' + idlistplatforms);
            }
            update idlistplatforms;
        }
    }

}
```

I think the problem is because of the **update** part. Can someone please edit my code so that I will overcome that error?

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3):

In short, DML operations are not allowed in a class constructor because it can be a reason of a dangerous side effects.

Good answer to your question you can find [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28853/2423)

Answer (score 3):

sorry dude but just like pavel said you can't put DML in you constructor.

what you can do is to let the Visual force page to load and then call you apex with Remote Action to make DML queries.

Make sure that you do that in document.ready of jquery.